# Given a closed convex curve, let a central convex curve circumscribe it, then what is the minimum of B/A?(A and B are their corresponding areas)

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry, differential-equations, projective-geometry

I guess the answer is 2, but I cannot prove it.

I mean supermum of the minimum B/A among all A.

Notice:

Central convex curve means the convex curve is symmetric about a point in it, that is, when you rotate the curve 180 degrees about the point, it comes back to the original curve.

For triangle, which is considered the most asymmetric, 2 is a lower bound. That is why I think 2 is a lower bound for all other convex curves

I need to calculate a minimum r=B/A such that for all of the colsed convex curves，their always exists a central convex curve (with area A*r) circumscribe it. Please help me, a lot of thanks.

Comment: Suppose we have two circles, one inside the other with the same center. In terms of theory, `B/A` can go to `1` in limit.

Comment: If the first curve is "central convex", the ratio is obviously 1. If not, the problem seems terrible.

Comment: I know this, but I do not mean a certain case. I need to calculate the lower bounds for all of the convex curves

Comment: **I need to calculate a minimum r=B/A such that for all of the colsed convex curves，their always exists a central convex curve (with area A*r) circumscribe it. Please help me, a lot of thanks.**

Comment: Please don't shout. We understood that you want this question answered.

Comment: Question answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900257/for-all-closed-convex-curves-let-central-convex-curves-circumscribe-them-what